# AChartEngine Second Series

Tags: android, achartengine, series

I have looked around online for some help with this, but found nothing.
I am trying to add a second series to my graph. Each series ought to have a separate scale. However, I cannot get my second series to acknowledge my second scale. Both series seem to want to stick to the first scale (the "zeroth" scale). Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

```
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer(2);
        renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(10);
        renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(25);
        renderer.setLabelsTextSize(20);
        renderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
        renderer.setMargins(new int[] { 30, 30, 30, 30 });
        renderer.setXLabelsPadding(20);
        renderer.setYLabelsPadding(20);

        renderer.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.lightest));
        renderer.setYAxisAlign(Align.LEFT, 0);
        renderer.setXAxisMin(d1.getTime(), 0);
        renderer.setXAxisMax(d2.getTime(), 0);
        renderer.setYAxisMax(prepMaxVal+1, 0);
        renderer.setYAxisMin(prepMinVal, 0);

        renderer.setYAxisAlign(Align.RIGHT, 1);
        renderer.setXAxisMin(d1.getTime(), 1);
        renderer.setXAxisMax(d2.getTime(), 1);
        renderer.setYAxisMax(timesMaxVal, 1);
        renderer.setYAxisMin(timesMinVal, 1);

        renderer.setXLabels(daysBetween(d1, d2));
        renderer.setXLabelsAngle(45);
        renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
        renderer.setChartTitle("Distance and Pace");
        renderer.setDisplayValues(true);

        XYSeriesRenderer  r = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        r.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.main));
        r.setLineWidth(3);

        XYSeriesRenderer  r2 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        r2.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.oldcontrast));
        r2.setLineWidth(3);

        dataset.addSeries(0, preparingDistancechart);
        renderer.addSeriesRenderer(0, r);
        dataset.addSeries(1, times);
        renderer.addSeriesRenderer(1, r2);

        GraphicalView chartView = ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(getActivity(), dataset, renderer, "MM/dd/yyyy");
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.graphicalLayout);
        layout.addView(chartView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Comment: See this for a multiple scales example: https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/MultipleTemperatureChart.java